# Component does not re-render when State is updated using react, redux and immer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immer.js

I have a simple code which containing a PostFeed component to show feeds and PostItem component inside it which shows each feed. in PostItem user can do like feed and here a service call and a number of likes will change. if the current user has liked the feed, the thumb will have a blue color.

everything works fine when the page refreshed, but when the feed gets to like or dislike, the state gets update and a number of likes changed truly but the component color does not change.
In order to prevent Immutableily, I have used *Immer*.

Here is the code

```
//PostFeed Component
class PostFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;

    return posts && posts.map(post => <PostItem key={post._id} post={post} />);
  }
}

//PostItem Component
class PostItem extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.post) {
      this.setState({ post: nextProps.post });
        }
      }

  onLikeClick(id) {
    this.props.addLike(id);
  }

  isCurrentUserLike(likes: ILike[]) {
    const { auth } = this.props;
    if (likes.filter(like => like.user === (auth.user as any).id).length > 0) {
      return <i className="fas fa-thumbs-up text-info" />;
    } else {
      return <i className="fas fa-thumbs-up" />;
    }
  }

render() {
const { post, auth } = this.props;
return (
      <div className="card card-body mb-3">

...

<button onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, post._id)} type="button" className="btn btn-light mr-1">

        // This line does not re-render                 
        {this.isCurrentUserLike(post.likes)}

       <span className="badge badge-light">{post.likes.length}</span>
    </button>
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addLike})(
  PostItem
);
```

this is acition:

```
export const addLike = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post(`/api/posts/like/${id}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: "POST_LIKED",
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_ERRORS",
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

and this is reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draft): any => {
    switch (action.type) {

 case "POST_LIKED":
        draft.posts = substitudePost(draft.posts, action.payload);
        draft.loading = false;
        break;
}}
    )}

const substitudePost = (posts, post) => {
  const index = posts.findIndex(i => i._id == post._id);
  if (index > -1) posts[index] = post;
  return posts;
}
```

and these are Data types:

```
 interface initialFeedState= {
  posts: IPost[],
  post: IPost,
  loading: false
};

interface IPost  {
  _id: string;
  user: IUser;
  likes: ILike[];
  comments: IComment[];
  date: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code of onClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this, post._id)}

Comment: @Domino987 , I update the code and add onlikeclick and its action.

Comment: Can you console log the post after the axios call? Because your code looks fine.

Comment: where should change the color? i didn't get it. It is on text-info className?

Comment: @Domino987, when i debug the code, every thing works fine but the component does not change view.

Comment: @KevynKlava, isCurrentUserLike - this function add a css class to change the color.

Comment: @navid Can you console.log likes and auth in isCurrentUserLike before and after liking a page?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line

```
if (likes.filter(like => like.user === (auth.user as any).id).length > 0) {
```

You are comparing the user **object** with authenticated user **id**, they will never be the same. And you can use the some function like this

```
if (likes.some(like => like.user.id === auth.user.id)) {
```

Comment: like.user containing the id of user whohas liked to post. so it is comparing truely.